# Why does vuetify in my project break when used in .js file vs .vue file

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuetify.js

When I include vuetify `Vuetify.use(vuetify)` from my index.js file I get this error

```
vue.esm.js?a026:591 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-app> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

but when I include it in my projects App.vue file it works just fine. Why does this happen?

## index.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import StorePlugin from "./store/index";
import LibrariesPlugin from "./plugins/libraries";
import App from "./components/App";
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.use(StorePlugin);
Vue.use(LibrariesPlugin);
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

## App.vue

```
<template>
    <v-app>
     // other custom components
    </v-app>
</template>
<script>
   import Vue from "vue";
   import Vuetify from "vuetify";
   Vue.use(Vuetify);
   export default {}
</script>
```

I have also tried the fixes with adding name to the components and that didn't change anything either.

Comment: It is weird. I am including Vuetify in `main.js` and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out it wasn't working because I had two versions of Vue installed. I removed the second version *(which was an older version of Vue)* and then importing Vuetify in `index.js` worked fine. I'm still not sure why Vuetify worked with duplicate versions of Vue when included in `App.vue` and not when in `index.js`, but removing that second instance of Vue fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove these imports from App.vue and leave them only in index.js

Comment: when I put them in index.js it stops working, I want to know why?

Comment: Are you using the vue-cli 2.x with webpack template? Did you scaffolded new project with vue init webpack my-project?

Comment: no i didn't scaffold it and i have vue-cli 2.9.6 installed

Comment: Then sorry, I have no idea what did you do.